# Sort a returned object by its boolean parameters [Ruby]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

i think i used the right terminology for what i need, i currently have a database call in my home_controller that is returning a call to my database with all the entries in that table specified, Freelancer.
There is an attribute on these records that has either a true or false value, which is "featured".
I need a way to call a sort method, or some other way, on that object with the true being first and then the false being afterwards, i tried using this code

```rb
def index
    @freelancers = Freelancer.all
    p 'below im outputting featured freelancer i hope'
    @freelancers.sort_by { |row| [row.featured ? 0 : 1, row.id]}
    p @freelancers
  end
```

But unfortunately this did not work, can anyone advise me on a way to get this to work? Id rather have the sorted object returned as is, rather then assigning it to a new one. Just for future features of adding pagy and a filter by cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [order](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order) method

```rb
def index
  @freelancers = Freelancer.order(featured: :desc)
end
```

Comment: Hello Stefan again! :D Should i put this below the @freelancers = Freelancer.all ?

Comment: No, Instead `Freelancer.all`

Comment: Thank you, that was much easier then i thought, forgot about .order calls